# Preventing Merge and Branch your own code on TFS

Tags: c#, tfs, policy, subscriber

I am working on TFS (v 16...) to prevent a collection with Test and Main branches from doing merge or branch operations on its own.I am currently trying to do this on the server side using ISubscriber(Assembly Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=16.0.0.0.0).I cannot reach the owner of the code merged from the Test branch.

Subscriber(Assembly Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=16.0.0.0.0).I cannot reach the owner of the code merged from the Test branch.

Comment: Please clarify if you're referring to TFS (non-git) branches - or git-in-TFS branches?

Comment: For the case without "git".This problem is valid for tfvc.

Comment: To prevent other users from doing merge or branch operations, you can set all folder/branch level permissions except "Read" to "Deny" for the target user. If you are not sure who merged into the main branch, you can view the history of the main branch on the UI.

Comment: Please take the time to write and format your questions so that they are easy to read and understand